# Puppeteer second tab throws chrome-error while running as Docker container

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to run a nodejs app with puppeteer. It runs fine outside of Docker, but I get chrome-error://chromewebdata/ for one of the tabs if I build the Docker image and run it in the container. I expect there to be another tab. Puppeteer 10.4.0 and Docker image for node build is node:16.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--no-sandbox',
  ],
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
// Have tried setting a timer here too
const secondPage = (await browser.pages())[2];

// The below are the pages. 
[
 'about:blank',
 'http://host.docker.internal:3000/',
 'chrome-error://chromewebdata/'
]
```